# Git ERROR: Permission to user1/repoA.git denied to user2

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, configuration

I have two github accounts and I am trying to configure github, my environment and ssh keys in order that I'm able to push to any repo whether it lies in my github.com/user1 or github.com/user2 account. I have spent hours attempting to get this right following all the resources I can find, alas I seem to be lacking the understanding to get this sorted out. Can anyone help me get this configures correctly?

Each of my two accounts on github.com is set up with different email addresses; `github.com/user1 = 'user1@user1.com` and `github.com/user2 = user2@user2.com`.

I have two generated SSH keys the first in `.ssh/id_rsa` & `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and this SSH key is saved in `github.com/user1`. The 2nd SSH key in `.ssh/user2` .ssh/user2_rsa`and saved in`github.com/user1`.

I have a `.ssh/config file` which contains:

```
Host user1.github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user1
Host user2.github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When i run `ssh-add -l` I see both keys are 'loaded'.

When i run `ssh -T git@user1.github.com` i get `Hi user2! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

When i run `ssh -T git@user2.github.com` i get `Hi user2! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

I can successfully push to a repo in 'github.com/user2'.

I cannot push to a repo in 'github.com/user1', with below error message;

```
ERROR: Permission to user1/repo.git denied to user2.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My `.gitconfig' file contains:

```
[user]
    name = my full name 
    email = user1@user1.com
[GitHub]
   user = user1
```

From what I can see it seems that my local environment, cmd, has me stuck as user2 and will not allow user2 to commit to the user1 github account. But a) i thought the script in `.ssh/config` should recognise that when i'm pushing to user1 it should use the user1 ssh and visa versa, but this does not seem to be happening and b) my `.gitcofig` has my `user.email` and my GitHub user as user1 which conflicts with my being authenticated as user2 after running `ssh -T ...`.

I've tried so many things my knickers are in a proper twist on this one now. Can anyone hel get me set up properly with this and or guide me as to how I can erase all SSh's and start over and set up correctly (note that I have a Heroku account set up also that needs to be configured).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 2nd SSH key in `.ssh/user2 .ssh/user2_rsa`

Yet, your `.ssh/config` uses `id_rsa` for `user2.github.com`

```
Host user2.github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                      ^^^^^^
```

And `user1.pub` public key seems to be registered on `user2` account, since a `ssh -T git@user1.github.com` returns a `Hi user2!`

Check your local config, and check also on github side which public key has been added to which account.

---

Note: Adding the user `git` in the `.ssh/config` file  is recommended:

```
Host user2.github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User git <=====
```

That way, the URL becomes:

```
ssh -T user2.github.com
```

Comment: Thanks VonC, appreciated. I was in a right mess so I just decided to delete all keys and start all over again and all is working fine now. I shall delete this Q as i'm not sure it'll be constructive for others.

Comment: @jbk No, you can leave the question, as it illustrates how ssh/config works.

Comment: I have the same problem, but on Windows. Advice how to deal with it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The answer is the same, except `~` is replaced by `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 1):

**On Linux Platform**

The problem already explains  pretty nicely what the exact issue is.
Also, @VonC answered the question neatly as well.
I would like to add just a little information which might help some other noobs like me.

- First, the config file in ~/.ssh/ directory is not generated by default. In my case it was not present by default, but one can easily create one by navigating to the .ssh directory (or perhaps directly as well, whatever you like) and executing the command.

  `nano config`

Then simply paste what is also mentioned in the problem above.

```
Host user1.github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user1
Host user2.github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user2
```

I would suggest not using the default names for the keys when creating an SSH key like 'id_rsa'. If you don't specify any name while creating an SSH key, it will name it 'id_rsa' and then it created confusion later when you try to recall what application the key was created for. It's better to rename the key like 'github_user1', or something like that (let your imagination go wild).

After this, you can test your keys using cmd

```
ssh -T git@user1.github.com
```

which should return

```
Hi user1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Similarly for user2 as well.

- Secondly, if the system still uses the key of first user while
  authenticating for second user, it may sound cliche but simply
  restart your linux system. Everytime we boot the system and use an
  SSH key, the os caches the used SSH key and restarting the system
  clears the cache. Though, you can also use cmd to clear the cache.