# Cannot access remote machine git repository

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, bitbucket

My friend and I work on different branches in a bit-bucket repository and then we merge to one branch. And my friend clones the master branch to our server.

Now, only he can pull and push that remote machine repository. I also login using ssh, but I couldn't do pull and push. When I type pull, I show, my friend git link to type password.

I am also admin of the bit-bucket repository. Please, hope someone help.

I also create my global user and give global email to git repository, but still not change anything.

Comment: It's pretty hard to follow you. So could you please rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: @ckruczek , my English knowledge is poor. If I not answer , within next two, four hour , I will try to more explain trouble.

Answer (score 1):

> I also , login ssh  when I type Pull , I show , my friend git link to type password

Since it is an ssh url, that means it search by default for the private/public ssh keys in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.

If you are both logged in with the same user, that key is the same.

Make sure you don't use the same account, or, if you do, add in `~/.ssh` a `config` file which can reference two sets of ssh keys (with two public keys registered on the Bitbucket repo).
See [this question as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32958482/6309).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will refer link. but I have little confuse, You mean , I also should create new User in my remote machine ? (I used digitalOcian server machine)

Comment: @uma I might be confised mysef by the "I also , login ssh": are you logged in to your digitalOcean  first, in order to do some git pull from the bitbucket repo from that digitalOcean server? If you are logged in on that server, are you logged in with the same account as your colleague?

Comment: yes , this is official server so, both we access same Ip and password to longing digitalOcean server(ssh loging same). when I go to our site folder , I can do only execute 'commit' and 'add' git command. I cannot pull request execute. when I type 'git pull' , show my friend git link. my friend can do pull , and push . he also clone this repository.

Comment: @uma that means you are both using the same ~/.ssh. But you expect Bitbucket to see you as two different people. You need to generate your own set own ssh keys, as illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/q/32958482/6309

Comment: @uma See also https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html for all the details.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this.

Comment: I understand what you mean, he will clone this repo. using his SHH key link. so, I think , You mean I also add my SHH key to repo . Isn't it?

Comment: @uma exactly: Bitbucket will then be able to authenticate you (to recognize you) because you will be using your own ssh key, registered for that Bitbucket repo.