# Gitlab can't clone repository even though ssh works

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

As the title states, I can't clone a repository from a Gitlab 6 server even though the ssh seems to work.

When trying to clone, it looks like this:

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.de:1337/project/repository.git
Cloning into 'repository'...
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In the project, I have the role of "developer" which should have the rights to clone a repository?

I also checked if my SSH public key is working

```
ssh git@domain.de -p 1337 -T
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
```

More irritating to me is that for a friend of mine seems everything to work fine.

**Edit:**
The main indicator for the problem stated here is the greeting from the SSH Test. In an working enviroment it should be greeting you with your name instead Anonymous!

Comment: recognizing this question is old, but still interesting - why not use git clone git@domain.de:project/repository.git? - is this common pattern not an option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the scp-like syntax:

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.de:1337:project/repository.git
```

That forces the [use of `~/.ssh/config`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32958482/6309) actually, which means the url can be simplified to `gitlab:project/repositoriy.git`.

But it turned out to be an ssh key issue in the gitlab server `~gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys` (a bit like in [issue 4730](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4730#issuecomment-85232416)).
The [OP Gelix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2708038/felix) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837103/gitlab-cant-clone-repository-even-though-ssh-works/33837230?noredirect=1#comment55450558_33837230):

> I removed my key from Gitlab, manually from `authorized_keys`, readded it on Gitlab. Everything fine now.
>   Message with SSH Test is now also `Welcome to GitLab, Felix *****`!

(instead of `Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!`)

Comment: Ended in the same error. To use the 1337 port I created a host in my ssh config which otherwise would default to 22 with the scp syntax

Comment: @Felix with a `~/.ssh/config`, your url would become (assuming a `Host` entry named `gitlab`, for instance): `gitlab:project/repository.git`: would that work?

Comment: That's exactly what I did and resulted in the same error. `ssh gitlab -T` showed the success message so I assume no spelling mistake in the config file

Comment: @Felix then it must be a right issue on GitLab side: you must not be declared in that project (or that project group/name is incorrect, wrong case)

Comment: @Felix Do you still have the issue?

Comment: Problem is still existing. I have now owner rights of the project. It seems that as you said the repo is not found but that makes no sense to me as I copy it directly from the gitlab :|

Comment: @Felix Are you registered as a contributor (like "Developer" role for instance) on that project on GitLab server side?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the group owning the project but also a individual team member as developer. I also removed myself as a team member for testing due to possible double right conflicts

Comment: @Felix Is there some kind of inconsistency in the GitLab `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4730#issuecomment-85232416)

Comment: Perfect! I removed my key from Gitlab, manually from authorized_keys, readded it on Gitlab. Everything fine now.

Message with SSH Test is now also `Welcome to GitLab, Felix *****!` if you edit your answer I will check it! :) Thanks a lot again

Comment: @Felix Great \o/ I have edited the answer to reflect the actual resolution of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with my private GitLab-CE hosted server. Reconfiguring the GitLab saved me. I have tried editing the local config file and adding the host also, but it didn't work. This worked for me.

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```