# Github: Permission to user1/repo.git denied to user2

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've been having major issues with having two Github accounts on my device. I believe I have setup things up correctly and have extensively reviewed other posts.

I am consistently getting this error no matter what I do (rohanset is my school github, while roronyc19 is my personal):

```
roronyc19@Rohans-MacBook-Pro testgit % git push -u origin master
ERROR: Permission to rohanset/test.git denied to roronyc19.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My .ssh config file looks as follows:

```
Host github.com-rohanset
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com-roronyc19
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal
```

I have added the keys to the ssh-add manager and can see them.

Even if I try ssh-ing with the correct profile, github is still using the old username

```
roronyc19@Rohans-MacBook-Pro testgit % ssh -T git@github.com-rohanset
Hi roronyc19! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I have tried updating my user.name, user.email in both local and global scope to rohanset, the correct one.

I have also tried updating the remote origin to use the correct profile (using git config --list):

```
user.name=rohanset
user.email=rohanset@umich.edu
...
remote.origin.url=git@github.com-rohanset:rohanset/test.git
...
```

There is no mention in Keychain of git, so I assume this is not my problem either.

Lastly, I tried ssh-add -D and then readding only the ssh file for rohanset, but this did not help either.

I seem to be having the same issue as:
[Git ERROR: Permission to user1/repoA.git denied to user2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958482/git-error-permission-to-user1-repoa-git-denied-to-user2)
But that question was unresolved and no solution worked for me.

I really appreciate any help!

edit1: Thanks for the comments! Updated remote origin to correct one, but did not help.

Also tried thanks to @lucidbot:

```
roronyc19@Rohans-MacBook-Pro testgit % ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 github.com-rohanset
PTY allocation request failed
Hi roronyc19! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Shared connection to github.com closed.
```

Not sure how to interpret the failed request but it didn't change anything. I'm also not completely sure how to change my ssh config file like it says in the answer you linked...

Comment: just to be sure at least that works as intended, does explicitly specifying the command line flags like [here](https://superuser.com/a/773135/291007) work? It should.. but if not it would be one further piece of info

Comment: Also consider the [last two paragraphs of this answer](https://superuser.com/a/436015/291007)

Comment: Your `user.name` setting is **irrelevant**; ignore it. Your URL in your `remote.origin.url` is literally `git@github.com`, not `git@github.com-rohanset`. This part *is* relevant. However, your test with `ssh -T git@github.com-rohanset` shows that you're providing the wrong public key when using that as the ssh argument, so you'll need to fix that *first*.